# transform a list of pairs into pair of list using list comprehension

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Haskell

```
split:: [(a,b)] -> ([a],[b])
```

Function should return

```
split [(1,’a’), (2,’b’), (3,’c’)] = ([1,2,3], "abc")
```

Please how do i do it using list comprehension? thanks

Comment: Theres always this: `split = foldr (\(a, b) (as, bs) -> (a:as, b:bs)) ([], []) `

Answer (score 4):

The **split** function you are looking for already exists in the standard Haskell Prelude library; it is called **unzip**.

Using list comprehensions:

```
split xs = ([a | (a,_) <- xs], [b| (_,b) <- xs])
```

Answer (score 2):

While you've got a correct answer, here's one way to approach this more systematically.

If you break the problem down into

1. Making a list of the "firsts", and
2. Making a list of the "seconds", and
3. Making a pair of those lists,

you get

```
firsts  xs = [a | (a, _) <- xs]
seconds xs = [b | (_, b) <- xs]
split xs = (firsts xs, seconds xs)
```

and then you can "inline" the auxiliary functions

```
split xs = ([a | (a, _) <- xs], [b | (_, b) <- xs])
```